# Werkzeug URL map with method-based endpoints return only Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, methods, werkzeug, url-mapping, http-status-code-405

Here is a truncated version of our mapping:

```
url_map = Map([
    Rule('/actions/<int:id>/', endpoint='actions.get_action', methods=('GET')),
    Rule('/actions/<int:id>/', endpoint='actions.put_action', methods=('PUT')),
    Rule('/actions/<int:id>/', endpoint='actions.dismiss_action', methods=('DELETE'))
])
```

After much searching, I found some examples of people doing the same at ( http://nullege.com/codes/search/werkzeug.routing.Rule ) ... but when I do this, all THREE return as method not allowed.  I could potentially do

```
... methods=('GET', 'PUT', 'DELETE') ...
```

and have an endpoint that dispatches the request to alternate functions, but from what I've read, my mapping should just work or, at the very least, COULD work if I was privy to the correct syntax (which I've not found outside of the link above.)

Any ideas as to what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In your rule list, the methods parameters, shouldn't they be lists? Something like

```
... methods=('GET',) ...
```

Note the comma that makes it a tuple.